# How to access the injected service in my formHandler?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to use the ewz_search.lucene service in my (FOSUserBundle) profileFormHandler. 
I've injected the ewz_search.lucene service into the formHandler service like so:

```
application_sonata_user.form.handler.profile:
    class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Form\Handler\ProfileFormHandler
    arguments: ["@fos_user.profile.form", "@request", "@fos_user.user_manager", "@ewz_search.lucene"]
    scope: request
    public: false
```

I'd like to access this service in the handler so I can add an index to the username field
I've tried something like $this->lucene->updateIndex(), but it doesn't know the property $lucene.

References:
https://github.com/excelwebzone/EWZSearchBundle
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#referencing-injecting-services

Comment: Double check if you assigned `lucene` service instance to class member ...